# RuleBasedCollator not sorting as expected with special character (dash) in quotes

Tags: java, collation

I would like the dashes to come after spaces. But it's not working. The dashes are being ignored even though they are enclosed in quotes. Why?

> Text-Argument: A text-argument is any sequence of characters,
>   excluding special characters (that is, common whitespace characters
>   [0009-000D, 0020] and rule syntax characters [0021-002F, 003A-0040,
>   005B-0060, 007B-007E]). If those characters are desired, you can put
>   them in single quotes (e.g. ampersand => '&'). Note that unquoted
>   white space characters are ignored; e.g. b c is treated as bc.

```
public static void sortFile() throws IOException, ParseException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\def.txt"),
                    "Cp1252"));     

    RuleBasedCollator myCollator = (RuleBasedCollator) Collator.getInstance(Locale.US);

    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {            
        line = line.replace(" ", "' '");
        line = line.replace("\t", "'\t'");
        line = line.replace("-", "'-'");
        lines.add(line);
    }
    br.close();

    Collections.sort(lines, myCollator);

    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("C:\\defsorted.txt"), "Cp1252"
        ));     

    for (String line1 : lines) {                
        line1 = line1.replace("' '", " ");
        line1 = line1.replace("'\t'", "\t");
        line1 = line1.replace("'-'", "-");
        out.write(line1 + "\r\n");
    }
    out.close();
}
```

Input File:

```
bottom
bottom antiquark
bottom dollar
bottom-dweller
bottom-dwelling
bottome
bottom feeder
bottomfeeder
bottom-feeder
bottom feeders
bottomfeeders
bottom feeding
```

Sorted File:

```
bottom
bottom antiquark
bottom dollar
bottom-dweller
bottom-dwelling
bottom feeder
bottom-feeder
bottom feeders
bottom feeding
bottome
bottomfeeder
bottomfeeders
```

Expected result:

```
bottom
bottom antiquark
bottom dollar
bottom feeder
bottom feeders
bottom feeding
bottom-dweller
bottom-dwelling
bottom-feeder
bottome
bottomfeeder
bottomfeeders
```